# BINARY or ANOVA test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, binary-data, anova, statistical-significance

I'm confused on what test to use for an experiment I have conducted over the past months.
Let me give you some context:

I ran a germination experiment, sowed 900 seeds total in trays of 40 in a nursery in a way that all can be treated as equal except for the treatment they receive.
Treatment groups were divided into 100.

The results are cumulative germination per group, counting all the seeds that germinated.
What am I supposed to use here? Can I use an `ANOVA` with 99 degrees of freedom, should I be using something with 2 degrees of freedom because every treatment was sown into 3 (technically 2.5) trays, or should I be using some sort of binary test with 100 repetitions and 99 degrees of freedom because the only result I am getting is `DID GERMINATE (1)` or `DID NOT GERMINATE (0)?`

I'm doing this in R and have a large portion of my script set up already, but I can't determine what test I should use to find out of any treatment groups have significant differences between them.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Choosing a statistical method is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I've noted to migrate to [stats.se] where questions of a statistical nature are more appropriate.

Comment: We need a little bit more information/clarification please. Are there 9 = 900/100 distinct treatments?  How are the treatments divided across trays -- 2 trays of 40 and a tray with only 20 seeds, or are there trays that are split evenly between two different treatments ... ?  I think you probably want to use some form of binomial GLM, but it's not clear yet whether binomial, quasi-binomial, beta-binomial or mixed binomial is most appropriate ...

Comment: Sorry about that MrFlick, I didn't even know this existed! Thanks for moving. @BenBolker: There are indeed trays split evenly between two different treatments, and there are 9 distinct treatments indeed, each with seeds. Thanks for looking into it!